how to set default textstyle for text widget using theme?
static TextTheme lightTextTheme=TextTheme(
    headlineLarge: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 30,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:MyColors.darkColor),
    headlineMedium: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:  MyColors.darkColor),
    headlineSmall: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:  MyColors.darkColor),

    bodyLarge: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 30,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,color:  MyColors.darkColor),
    bodyMedium: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,color:  MyColors.darkColor),//used as default
    bodySmall: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,color:  MyColors.darkColor),

    titleLarge: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 14,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:  MyColors.darkColor),
    titleMedium: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 10,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:  MyColors.darkColor),
    titleSmall: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 8,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:  MyColors.darkColor),



    labelLarge: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 14,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,color: MyColors.darkColor.withOpacity(0.8)),
    labelMedium: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 10,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,color:  MyColors.darkColor.withOpacity(0.8)),
    labelSmall: const TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 8,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,color:  MyColors.darkColor.withOpacity(0.8)),


  );

by default it is taking bodymedium as default and i want to change it to labelSmall for default.
so that whenever i use Text('hello') it should be labelSmall as a style.
here i dont want to replace properties code of bodyMedium to labelSmall..thats not what i want.

Try this in your main file -- MaterialApp( theme: ThemeData(textTheme: lightTextTheme.copyWith(bodyMedium: lightTextTheme.labelSmall,),)
